# CakePHP - BlogTutorial -

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I was following pdf blog tutorial, and in the PostsController where $this->Post should be available another method postConditions() is the only choice. According to the PDF Post is accessible due to the naming conventions. But it is not in my case.

I have created:

model Post.php - according to the pdf
Controller PostsController - according to the pdf

I use PhpStorm IDE to help me out with the stuff....

What did i do wrong? Could someone help me out?

I am using Cake 2.3.0 Stable on localhost XAMP

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean autocomplete in your editor is not working?

CakePHP dynamically loads classes as and when they are references, your editor does not, so it is unaware of what Post is as it doesn't know anything about it.

I don't use PhpStorm, but here's someone who's says they've got it working: http://blog.hwarf.com/2011/08/configure-phpstorm-to-auto-complete.html

Comment: Yes. You assumption is perfect. I have used phpstorm with my own mvc stuff and autocomplete was working ok and picking things up. Oh well...will have to hack some ide here and there :)